# Positioned "fixed" div is centered. Positioned "relative" div is centered. They both appear a little off

Tags: css

Here's what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6kuB.png

Here's the CSS:

```
#header{
background:url('header.png');
border-radius:15px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 9px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 9px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 9px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.75);
height:145px;
width:855px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
position:fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
top:-10px;
max-height:145px;
max-width:855px;
}

#centered_background{
background-color:#F2F2F2;
width:845px;
height:1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
top:-15px;
border-radius:20px;
border:4px solid #2E2E2E;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the "fixed" aspect of the header. But I don't exactly know.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using instead of fixed, relative. Just a thouhgt...

Comment: Relative does fix it, but I'd prefer it be a fixed element.

Comment: Have you given whatever is wrapped around `#centered_background` a definite width? Perhaps `html, body { width:100%; }`

Comment: Ah, that was it! I had my width at 98% for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Is `#centered_background` shifted left because of scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

The width of the wrapper needs to be defined for `margin:auto` to work.

```
html, body { width:100%; }
```